# How to include CMake files from source tree of included project

Tags: cmake

I'm setting up a CMake based build system for an old framework, written in C. It consists of a single binary, some core libraries and many dynamically linked libraries, which are built against the core libraries. My goal is to structure those libraries in several CMake projects ("base framework", "extension libraries", …), supporting two scenarios:

- Independent build of extension libraries against base framework's build tree:

  ```
  - base_framework/
    - cmake/
      - functions.cmake
    - core_libraries/
    - CMakeLists.txt
  - extension_libs/
    - lib1/
    - lib2/
    - CMakeLists.txt
  ```

  For this scenario, I use

  ```
  export(EXPORT foo
    FILE FooFrameworkConfig.cmake)
  ```

  and

  ```
  find_package(FooFramework)
  ```

  and add the build tree to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when configuring the `extension_libs` project.
- Using base framework and extension libraries as sub-projects (e.g. as git submodules) of an application specific project:

  ```
  - my_project/
    - base_framework/
      - cmake/
        - functions.cmake
      - core_libraries/
      - CMakeLists.txt
    - extension_libs/
      - lib1/
      - lib2/
      - CMakeLists.txt
    - my_lib1/
    - CMakeLists.txt
  ```

  For this scenario, I use `add_subdirectory()` for both, the base framework and the extension libs.

(A third scenario would be building the extension libraries against an install tree of the base framework. Unfortunately, this scenario is currently prevented by other CMake problems.)

Now, I want to include the `base_framework/cmake/functions.cmake` file, containing some custom CMake functions for all libraries, into all projects' top-level `CMakeLists.txt`s in both scenarios.

For the second scenario, I simply set a cached CMake variable in `base_framework/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(BASE_FRAMEWORK_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    CACHE PATH "" FORCE)
```

and use this variable for including the functions file in `extension_libraries/CMakeLists.txt` as well as `my_project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(${BASE_FRAMEWORK_DIR}/cmake/functions.cmake)
```

But how do I find the `function.cmake` file in the base framework's source tree from `extenstion_libs/cmake` in the first scenario? All the directories (`base_framework`, `extension_libs`, base framework's build tree) may be anywhere on my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and great question! You haven't posted your `FooFrameworkConfig.cmake` file so I don't know what variables it defines (that can be used by the importing project). There are some standard variables defined [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#standard-variable-names), but you could have `FooFrameworkConfig.cmake` define a variable `FooFramework_CMAKE_MODULE_DIR` or something similar to provide the path to `base_framework/cmake` on your system.

Comment: I'm automatically generating the `FooFrameworkConfig.cmake` in the base framework's build tree using the `export(EXPORT …)` command in `base_framework/CMakeLists.txt`. If there's a way to get a variable with the source directory (dynamically) generated into this file, that would be great.

Comment: My first thought is to set the path `base_framework/cmake` in one of the properties of one of your exported targets, as some of these properties would be transported and accessible from the imported target (perhaps [`EXPORT_PROPERTIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html)?). Another option would be to use `file(APPEND FooFrameworkConfig.cmake ...)` to append a `set(MY_MODULE_PATH ...)` to the end of your configuration file, but that would be tricky depending on how often you plan to be building the base_framework libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment regarding your first scenario, it looks like you can set one of the properties of your exported `core_libraries` targets to contain the path to the `base_framework/cmake` modules. So you can set this in the `base_framework/CMakeLists.txt` file, let's set it in the [`LABELS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LABELS.html) target property. Then, we tell CMake to export the `LABELS` property using [`EXPORT_PROPERTIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html):

Your`base_framework/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
# Define the path to 'base_framework/cmake'
set(BASE_FRAMEWORK_CMAKE_MODULES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

add_library(CoreLibrary1 ...)
# Set the LABELS property, and tell CMake to export it.
set_target_properties(CoreLibrary1 PROPERTIES 
    LABELS "${BASE_FRAMEWORK_CMAKE_MODULES}"
    EXPORT_PROPERTIES "LABELS"
)
# Define the export 'foo'.
install(TARGETS CoreLibrary1 EXPORT foo DESTINATION /path/to/install/targets)
export(EXPORT foo FILE FooFrameworkConfig.cmake)
```

This will ensure the path to the `base_framework` CMake modules gets exported explicitly, and can be accessed when imported by another project:

Your `extension_libs/CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
find_package(FooFramework)
# Get the LABELS property from the imported target.
get_target_property(BASE_FRAMEWORK_MODULE_DIR CoreLibrary1 LABELS)
message(STATUS "BASE_FRAMEWORK_MODULE_DIR: ${BASE_FRAMEWORK_MODULE_DIR}")
```

With a debug `message()`, we can verify the CMake modules directory was imported:

```
BASE_FRAMEWORK_MODULE_DIR: /your/path/to/base_framework/cmake
```

---

**EDIT**: Instead of hijacking the `LABELS` target property, you could also use [`define_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/define_property.html) to define your own custom property for the target.